# How to find collar number in python

Tags: python, azure-pipeline-python-script-task

Take the first four characters of your surname - this is your dog name. Now, using the mapping suggested in Lecture 8 (slides 18 and 19), work out your collar number.
For example
"My dog name is LEVI and my collar number is 214873"

I want to know the method how it find.

Answer (score 0):

There is not enough information to answer this. What is "Lecture 8 slide 18 and 19"? If you ask a question at least provide the full context. As is, nobody will be able to answer this for you.

Comment: You are absolutely correct, but this would have been better as a comment instead of an answer to the question. As you said, this question is not answerable as of now